# displaying both date and time inputs from DateTImeField - Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a django template and a form where I want the user to input a date and time into the right fields and save the date and time into the database. I also want to initialize a specific time when ever the form is created. I currently have the date time field in my model and form but I am not sure how to get it to display both the time and date. it is only showing the default date so far. Here is the code that I have right now.

models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    calendar = models.ForeignKey(Calender, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Event')
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default='1950-01-01')
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(default='1950-01-01')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='example@example.com')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='location')
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='note')
    repeat = models.IntegerField()
    # 0 = no repeat
    # 1 = daily
    # 2 = weekly
    # monthly
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

forms:

```
class CreateEventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_date = forms.DateTimeField(
        label='Start',
        widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}),
    )
    end_date = forms.DateTimeField(
        label='End',
        widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'})
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['name', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'location', 'notes']
```

views:

```
form = CreateCalenderForm()
        parameters = {
            'form':form,
        }
        return render(request, 'calender/create_calender.html', parameters)
```

here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: You have TimeField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#timefield

Comment: I know there is a time field, but is there any way for me to have display both date and time inputs as one large imput from the DateTimeField. If I can, I would rather have one field over two different fields.... @guillermochamorro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DateTimeInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#datetimeinput) instead of DateInput in your widgets.

```
widget=forms.widgets.DateTimeInput(attrs={'type':'date'})
```

Comment: do I have to chage the attrs

Comment: @OmarJandali Yes it seems  `'type':'datetime-local'` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: @guillermochamorro this was the answer I've been on the quest for. Thank you!